# How to put a "View More " button click in my sticker app and that link it with my playstore app in Android

Tags: android, whatsapp, whatsapp-stickers

I am creating `sticker` app for `whatsapp` application using [this repository](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers). Everything works fine but right now I want to redirect to `Play store` when user will click on `sticker's` view more button.
 For more clarification, I have attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set fields with proper links `"ios_app_store_link" : "", "android_play_store_link" : "",` in contents.json and button will appear